# Entity Framework 7, MaxLength

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net5

I am trying to set MaxLength (ASP.Net 5, EF7) for string property on my model.

I can apply the migration with no problem at all. However, once the database created after running 'dnx ef database update', the model that I have set the MaxLength(10) for has data type varchar(1) in database.

I have checked the DBContext as well as the snapshot file, the column has max legnth 10.

I am not sure why code first is no picking up the MaxLength?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and I hope it is going to help others as well.

It turned out that I have had the Data Annotation on both the models and the dbcontext. It has to be on one of them.

I have removed all Data Annotations like IsRequired() and HasMaxLength from dbcontext, 'onModelCreating' method and only have them on my models. I have updated the database for InitialSchema migration and all the datatypes are now correct.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `MaxLength (10)`, use `StringLength(10)`.

`MaxLength` is used by previous EF versions only for schema generation in code first migration, while StringLength work for both, migrations and client side validation.

I cant tell you why `MaxLength` it is not working for you, it is possible that EF Core in its current development stage, is only taking in consideration `StringLength` by the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried once with StringLength, and have deleted the database and re-created it again by applying InitialSchema migration after adding new migration and did not work. I have also checked the InitialSchema file and have noticed that create table for that specific model did not pick up the right data type. It was just 'varchar' and not varchar(10). If I change it manually, I am sure it will work, but not sure why it is not picking it up from the model.